# confusion with this derivation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, inference, expected-value

I am working through some inference maths as described in a paper and have a doubt about a certain step. At one point, the authors have to compute an expectation of the following expression

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{w_i}{\sigma^2} (y_i - \beta x_i)^T(y_i - \beta x_i)
$$

Now the expectation has to be taken wrt to $Q(w_i)$. For me, this should be simply:

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} <w_i> (y_i - \beta x_i)^T(y_i - \beta x_i)
$$

where $<w_i>$ is the expectation operator applied. However, the authors write this as:
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} <w_i> y_ix_i
$$

I was wondering if there was some trick that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided, the answer to the question is that you are correct. The expression$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} <w_i> y_ix_i$$ is certainly inappropriate as definitely not equal to the expectation of$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{w_i}{\sigma^2} (y_i - \beta x_i)^T(y_i - \beta x_i)$$It would be nice though if you could provide an excerpt of the paper you refer to, so that we can check this is indeed what the author(s) meant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will attempt to make the question a bit more elaborate now. I just wanted to check if I did not miss anything. I might post another question in a while to keep things a bit less confusing.

Comment: I created a new thread showing my work and the expression from the paper here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180469/help-to-reproduce-this-derivation)

Comment: Cannot delete it as it has answers :/

Comment: than what hope do mortals like me have ;-)